# Unique constraint on column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I've this table:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Test ║ DATA ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 1  ║ Q    ║ I    ║
║ 2  ║ Q    ║ I    ║
║ 3  ║ Q    ║ A    ║
║ 4  ║ Q    ║ A    ║
║ 5  ║ Q    ║ A    ║
║ 6  ║ X    ║ A    ║
║ 7  ║ X    ║ A    ║
║ 8  ║ Z    ║ I    ║
║ 9  ║ Z    ║ I    ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

I want to apply Unique constraint on column value instead of column. So if Data contains I then no repetition and if it contains A. Then its fine
Result set will be

```
╔══════╦═══╗
║ Test ║ D ║
╠══════╬═══╣
║ Q    ║ I ║
║ Q    ║ A ║
║ Q    ║ A ║
║ Q    ║ A ║
║ X    ║ A ║
║ X    ║ A ║
║ Z    ║ I ║
╚══════╩═══╝
```

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support filtered indexes, but you can do essentially the same think using an expression:

```
create unique index idx_t_test_id
    on t(test, (case when data = 'I' then 0 else id end));
```

This assumes that `id` is unique and never 0.  This prevents duplicate "I" values in the table.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you just want a query result.  If so:

```
select test, data
from (select t.*,
             row_number(*) over (partition by test, data order by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or data <> 'I';
```